# Alternative proof of problem 16-21 of Lee's ISM: $\iota_X\mathsf{dVol}=\star(X^\flat)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

This is the problem 16-21 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth manifolds:

> **Problem 16-21:** Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold. Show $\iota_X\mathsf{dVol}_g=\star(X^\flat)$ for a vector field $X$.

I know a proof of that as follows: suppose $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis at $p\in M$  then
$$\iota_X\mathsf{dVol}_g(v_2,\dots,v_n)=\mathsf{dVol}_g(X,v_2,\dots,v_n)=g(X,v_1)$$
on the other hand and using $X=X^iv_i$ and $X^\flat=g_{ij}X^iE^j$
$$\star(X^\flat)(v_2,\dots,v_n)=\star(g_{ij}X^iE^j)(v_2,\dots,v_n)=g_{ij}X^i\star E^j(v_2,\dots,v_n)=\sum_jg_{ij}X^i \mathsf{dVol}_g(v_2,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_n)=g_{i1}X^i \mathsf{dVol}_g(v_1,\dots,v_n)=g(X,v_1). $$

I messed up a bit in the last two equalities. Anyway I want to know is there another proof and global (basis-free) proof? I think one can prove this just by using properties of interior multiplication and Hodge star. i.e. suppose $\eta$ be an arbitrary $n-1$-form then
$$\langle \iota_X\mathsf{dVol}_g,\eta\rangle = \langle \mathsf{dVol}_g,X^\flat\wedge\eta\rangle=??= \langle \star(X^\flat),\eta\rangle $$

How to fill the above gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the definition of the Hodge star operator, where for each one form $\alpha$, $\star \alpha$ is the $(n-1)$-form so that
$$\tag{1} \alpha \wedge \star  \alpha = \|\alpha\|^2\mathsf{dVol}, $$
here $\|\alpha\|^2 = g^{ij} \alpha_i\alpha_j$.

Then with $\alpha = X^\flat$,
$$ \|\alpha\|^2 = \|X\|^2 = g_{ij} X^i X^j$$
and by (1)

$$\| \alpha\|^2 \iota_X \mathsf{dVol}= \iota_X X^\flat\wedge \star X^\flat = \|X\|^2 \star X^\flat.$$

So $ \iota_X \mathsf{dVol} = \star X^\flat$.

Comment: And you have used of this property $\iota_X \star X^\flat=0$?

Comment: I have tried this over and over but I didn't knew $\iota_X \star X^\flat=0$.

Comment: Yes I did use that. On top of my head I don't have a coordinates/basis free proof. I will come back later for that @C.F.G

Comment: @C.F.G This is no proof but a geometric intuition: $\star X^{\flat}$ is a sort of "volume form" on $X^{\perp}$, and hence does not see the $X$ direction. This explains why $\iota_X \star X^{\flat} = 0$.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this argument per se, but one thing you said is incorrect: It's not true that  $\star \alpha$ is "the" $(n-1)$-form satisfying equation $(1)$. It's true that $\star$ satisfies $(1)$, but the equation doesn't uniquely determine $\star$. For example, let $\eta$ be any $(n-2)$-form whatsoever, and define $\widetilde\star\alpha = \star\alpha +\alpha\wedge\eta$; then $\alpha \wedge \widetilde \star  \alpha = \|\alpha\|^2\mathsf{dVol}$ for all $1$-forms $\alpha$.

Comment: The equation that uniquely determines $\star$ is $\alpha\wedge \star \beta = \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\mathsf{dVol}$ for all $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: @JackLee: You are right but we have fixed the Riemannian metric then Hodge star operator. So we know that it is unique. Isn't?

Comment: @C.F.G: It's true that for a fixed Riemannian metric, the Hodge star operator is uniquely defined. But that's not what I was referring to. This answer said that $\star \alpha$ is _**the**_ $(n-1)$-form satisfying equation $(1)$; but I gave an example of a different $(n-1)$-form that also satisfies $(1)$.

Comment: @JackLee: But to me you are using from a new Hodge star $\bar{\star}$ I think.

Comment: @C.F.G: That's the point. The Hodge star operator is _**not**_ the unique operator satisfying $(1)$, because my operator $\overline\star$ is another one.